# Populating contact number from address book works when contact is selected from list but fails when selected from search result

Tags: android

I use the following code to display list of contacts, and then retrieve contact number by selecting a contact. However, no number is retrieved when the list is searched for a contact and then selected from the search results. Do you have any idea on what am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading.

```
 private void registerLongClick() {
        TextView vonage_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vonage_number);
        vonage_number.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Phone.CONTENT_URI);  
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 1001);
                            return true;
            }
        });
    }    

    @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        String DEBUG_TAG = Constants.CALL_LOG_TAG_NAME;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            switch (requestCode) {  
            case 1001:  
                Cursor cursor = null;  
                String phone = "";  
                try {  
                    Uri result = data.getData();  
                    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "  
                            + result.toString());  

                    // get the contact id from the Uri  
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  

                    //query for phone number
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = " + id, null,
                            null);  

                    int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);  

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
                            phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);  
                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got phone: " + phone);  
                    } else {  
                        Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");  
                    }  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get phone data", e);  
                } finally {  
                    if (cursor != null) {  
                        cursor.close();  
                    }  
                    EditText phoneEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vonage_number);  
                    phoneEntry.setText(phoneEntry.getText().toString().trim()+phone);  
                    if (phone.length() == 0) {  
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No phone found for contact.",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    }  

                }  

                break;  
            }  

        } else {  
            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following for try {} catch {}.

```
try {
Uri contactData = data.getData();  
Log.debug("Got a contact result: " + contactData.toString());  
Cursor lookupCursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
if (lookupCursor.moveToFirst()) {                                       
        String lookupKey = lookupCursor.getString(lookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Log.debug("Lookup key: " + lookupKey);

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY + " LIKE '" + lookupKey + "'", null, null);  
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);  
                Log.debug("Got phone: " + phone); 
                cardNumber.setText(cardNumber.getText().toString().trim()+phone);  
                if (phone.length() == 0) {  
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No phone found for contact.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                }
        } 
        else {  
                Log.debug("No results");  
        } 
}  } catch (Exception e) {  
Log.error("Failed to get phone data:" + e.getMessage());  }
```

Comment: This piece of code displays the address list, with a row for every number for a contact, when I long press the Textfield. However, I just realized that when I search for a contact in this list, the search results doesn't display all the numbers that the searched contact has. Instead it displays just the contact name. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?